# Why convert jpeg into tfrecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ocr

I am inspecting some code in order to prepare to do my own ocr model and everyone converting jpeg into tfrecords. Why would they do that?

I found information about reducing occupied storage space, but both files occupy the same space.

Comment: Could you provide some of those information that you found where both files (TFRecord and JPEG) had the same size? This could help answering your question.